# New Developer trying to run task on Django without page reload. Possibly Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, alpine.js

Long time reader. First time poster. I've been using a Django site in a Windows only house for about 2 years. We're running scripts on Cisco network equipment with Paramiko. These tasks are run on multiple devices at times, and are time consuming (anywhere from 20 seconds to 3 minutes). I want to submit the script for processing and provide user live updates while the script runs. My research says that Javascript can do this with Ajax by not requiring a page reload. I'd want to attempt with Alpine.js due to its perceived simplicity. My background is in simpler static HTML/CSS type sites.

Has anyone tried the Django/Alpine combo at this time? I know Channels/Redis/Celery are popular, but these async requests are onesy twosy affairs, and I feel that a full task queue manager is complete overkill, while not being compatible with Windows for me at this time.

I'm not looking for specific code to fix my problem, more direction on how "best" to handle this issue of the user sitting and waiting on a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpine.js could work for your purposes. It's designed to play nicely with data fetching APIs and libraries such as the `fetch` Web API and JavaScript HTTP clients.

It's quite easy to adopt into your workflow since you can just include a HTML `script` tag and start writing Alpine.js components so it would be a good fit for a Django/other server-rendered type of application where this is one of the few instances where you need a bit of client-side interactivity.

As for the queuing/job tracking, really all you need is to keep track of script runs/jobs somehow and have an HTTP API endpoint which is able to expose this information to your frontend (ie. your Alpine.js widget) through a HTTP call.

Comment: Thank you. I'm exploring celery/redis on a Linux install also, but that will be a hard sell with the way things are. I know alpine should be able to read what it is given by Django. I'm more concerned with how to have Django keep alpine fed while the script runs.

Comment: There's a couple of ways to solve that issue, you can periodically fetch from the front-end to the backend, or you can do what's called long-polling (Django doesn't reply to a request until it has something to reply with) final option is to use sockets where the front-end and Django initiate a long-lived connection through which Django can push information to the client.